# How to change character"s name in LEGO Star Wars TCS in Android

Tags: android, lego-star-wars

I played it in my computer and I knew how to choose a custom name, but Android is different.
I downloaded official app 1 month ago and I don't know how to choose a custom name.

[image: Tipo raro means Weird guy]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in mobile versions.